# VS Code and Solidity files have a lot of warnings

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ide, visual-studio-code, warnings

Every time I use VS Code to develop Solidity, files I have a lot of this weird warnings saying:

> no-trailing-whitespace: Line contains trailing whitespace

I googled a bit and I understand why they are here. Although I would like to make my VS Code ignore them. Any help?

[image]

Comment: They are there because you have trailing whitespace... :-) Can't you just trim/remove them automatically? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884131/remove-trailing-spaces-automatically-or-with-a-shortcut

Comment: Also, I find it often helps (me at least) to show the whitespace and special characters in the editor -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140595/show-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason they exist is because you are using the [VS Code Solidity extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity). One feature of this extension is that it enables [Solium (now Ethlint)](https://github.com/duaraghav8/Ethlint). This is a linter that checks your code for errors and warnings, such as `no-trailing-whitespace: Line contains trailing whitespace`.

The best solution is to fix these warnings in your code, since the warnings are suggestions to follow best practices when writing Solidity. Code that follows the [Solidity style guide](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style-guide.html) should have no warnings like this.

If you want to remove some of these warnings without changing the code, you will need to edit your `settings.json` in VS Code. Within this file you can add the following line:

```
"solidity.soliumRules": {
}
```

In here, you can add rules that you want to ignore. For example, if you want to ignore the trailing whitespace warning, your `settings.json` file should look as follows:

```
"solidity.soliumRules": {
    "no-trailing-whitespace": "off"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you a lot, sir!